# ActionScript - variable declaration difference

Tags: actionscript-3

What is the difference between:

```
var arr3 = new Vector.<int>(6);
```

to

```
var arr3:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(6);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's the difference between declaring a variable type and not. While declaring a type is optional in AS3, best practice is to always declare a type.

The effect on your code this has is that if you declare a type, it will only compile and run properly if values of that type are assigned to the variable, and it will always be treated strictly as that type of object and nothing else. This is called "type safety". If you don't declare a type, you can assign anything to that variable and write code as if its any kind of object -- which may sound convenient, but it ends up making the code much more confusing, fragile and error prone.

Also note that not declaring a type is equivalent to declaring it as a "wildcard" type, like this: `var arr3:*`

Here's an example of untyped vs typed variables in code:

```
var untyped:*;
var string:String;
var number:Number;
var integers:Vector.<int>;

untyped = 1; // ok
untyped = "hello"; // ok
untyped = new Vector.<int>(); // ok

string = 1; // compile error
string = "hello"; // ok
string = new Vector.<int>(); // compile error

number = 1; // ok
number = "hello"; // compile error
number = new Vector.<int>(); // compile error

integers = 1; // compile error
integers = "hello"; // compile error
integers = new Vector.<int>(); // ok

if (untyped == 1) // ok
if (untyped == "hello") // ok
if (untyped.fixed) // compiles ok, but throws runtime error if "fixed" not defined on non-dynamic object

if (string == 1) // compile error, invalid comparison
if (string == "hello") // ok
if (string.fixed) // compile error, "fixed" not a property of String

if (number == 1) // ok
if (number == "hello") // compile error, invalid comparison
if (number.fixed) // compile error, "fixed" not a property of Number

if (integers == 1) // compile error, invalid comparison
if (integers == "hello") // compile error, invalid comparison
if (integers.fixed) // ok
```

These compile errors serve to show you mistakes you (or other developers) make before they become hard to hunt down problems in your SWF. For example, consider this untyped code:

```
var value = "hello";
if (value.x < 10) { }
```

That code doesn't make much sense, but it will compile. Then you will hit a runtime error when it tries to execute the `if` statement and can't find `x` on `String` "hello". In real life you might have a lot of hunting around to do to figure out what's wrong, especially if those 2 lines are not in close proximity to each other. However, if the programmer had specified a type on the variable, it would make the code more type safe:

```
var value:Point;
if (value.x < 10) { }
```

In this case the code would not compile if you tried to assign `value = "hello"`. The compiler would also validate that `x` is a property of type `Point`. If it wasn't, you'd get a compile error there, too. It even knows that `x` can be compared using `<` because it's a `Number`. This is all helpful to catch errors early rather than later.

In addition to making the code more clear to programmers, it also makes it more clear to authoring tools -- most authoring tools will give you much better code-completion suggestions for typed objects, since it knows exactly what properties and methods that type of object has.

For these reasons and probably others, you'll rarely find AS3 code examples that don't use strict type declarations, and most programmers (including me) will advise you always use them.

Answer (score 0):

Use second option. In first case you will get warning message:

```
Warning: Error code: 1008: variable 'arr3' has no type declaration.
```

Comment: That was not his question, he asked for the difference between both options.

Answer (score 0):

The first variable is untyped. If you declare a variable, but do not declare its data type, the default data type ***** will apply, which actually means that the variable is untyped. If you also do not initialize an untyped variable with a value, its default value is undefined.

The second one is typed as Vector.. A variable declared with the Vector. data type can only store a Vector instance that is constructed with the same base type int. For example, a Vector that's constructed by calling new Vector.() can't be assigned to a variable that's declared with the Vector. data type.

Answer (score -1):

Good answers from everyone. But the real answer goes a lot further. In case 1 the variable has no type and in case 2 the variable has a type. The difference is that in the second case the compiler is able to provide you with information in case something in your code goes wrong. In the first case the compiler might be able to provide some info or even no info at all in case something goes wrong in your code. If you work with untyped variables (case 1) you the developer are on your own if there's any error in your code. You'll be the one to look for them and try to fix them. In the second case the compiler will tell you where there's an error and most likely why there's an error.

Comment: I think you missed my answer. ;)